# AngularJs toggling between two buttons

Tags: angularjs, uibutton, angularjs-forms

I am trying to create a form with two buttons Edit & Submit. Submit is initially disabled . What I need to achieve is when Edit is clicked Submit button should be enabled and edit is disabled. Here is my code so far:

```
<div class="row">
    <button id="editBtn" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="submitEditedFormData()" class="btn modal-btn btn-default">Edit</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <button id="submitBtn" [disabled]="!isValid" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn modal-btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle the value of `isValid` when you click on edit button and you can do the same when you click on submit by adding a `(click)` event.

```
<div class="row">
    <button id="editBtn" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="submitEditedFormData();isValid=!isValid" class="btn modal-btn btn-default" [disabled]="isValid">Edit</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <button id="submitBtn" [disabled]="!isValid" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn modal-btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: and if i have a cancel button , on whose click i need to enable Edit button again and disable Cancel and Save ??

Comment: Do the same, just toggle the isValid on click of cancel button and edit will become enabled and use isValid for cancel too. You have to complement isValid based on your requirements

Comment: iHow can we achieve show/hide of button here with directive. Like when clicked edit > Save and Cancel shows up . When Clicked cancelled only Edit shows Up

Comment: You can use *ngIf="isValid" instead of disabled to show/hide buttons